# Exporting data from SQL server to Excel using python pyodbc and pandas Data frame

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, excel, pyodbc

I am new to Stack overflow as well as Python. Below is my program and I am trying to learn how to export data from SQL server to excel using python program. I know ways to directly exporting from SQL server, this is I am just trying to learn. Program below does not give any errors but it does just gives column headers but not actual data.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};SERVER=hostname;Database=Practice;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX")

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM insurance')

columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
data = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame([tuple(t) for t in cursor.fetchall()], columns=columns)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('foo.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='bar')
writer.save()
```

Comment: dude, maybe is on purpose but just in case, you have username and password there!!!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. But i changed before posting.

Answer (score 10):

easier than that!

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};SERVER=xxx;Database=xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx")

pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM insurance',cnxn).to_excel('foo.xlsx')
```

Comment: Awesome it worked pretty well. Can you please help me understand why did not work with my code?

Comment: Error i was getting was ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 64), indices imply (153, 64)

Comment: Ths answer solved me from an headache. There is just one typo:
`data = pandas.read_sql('SELECT * FROM insurance',cnxn)`
Should read 
`data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM insurance',cnxn)`